# Why it doesn't rain in winter much like summer(central asia)?

Tags: water, atmospheric-science

Why doesn't it rain in winter much like summer ( in  Central Asia)?

Although during winter water vapor in atmosphere should condense more to get precipitation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about physics. You could try asking on the [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Suresh Chandra Pal but for water vapours to condense we need to have them in the first place..

Answer (score 3):

Rain doesn't just depend on water vapours condensing. It also depends on the wind systems.

Central Asia lies in the northern hemisphere. This means when it's winter here, the sun is shifted more towards the southern hemisphere. Or in other words when the northern hemisphere is going through summer, the the southern hemisphere is going through winter. Where there is winter, there is high pressure and where there is summer,there is low pressure.

Winds travel from high pressure to low pressure. So in winter, most of the winds in central Asia are off-shore winds( from land to shore). This means that these winds will travel across the seas, become warm and moist, and cause rain over the low pressure zone in the southern hemisphere.

In summers in central Asia, the exact opposite process happens.

It is important to note that the bulk of the rain or water comes from these moist winds and not the water vapours already present over the land mass or in this case central asia